# How to enable jsp partitions in xml document?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, plugins, eclipse-pdt

I have created editor, which extends JSP Editor. I have added my own content assist, however I would like to be able to open XML documents, edit them using my editor and what is the most important to have content assist available. The problem is that, while editing xml I do not get content assist from JSP tags. Is there any possibility to enable JSP partitioning in xml document? Because I think it would resolve the problem, when text is properly partitioned, I obtain proper proposals.

Comment: @Ratna: look at the question tags.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Following file extensions are automatically recognized by JSP Editor in eclipse with WTP plugin installed.

- inc
- jsp
- jspx
- jsv
- jtpl

If the file you are adding is not in the listed file extesions you can add it to contenttypes in eclipse 
[ Window > Preferences > General > Content Types : In right pane expand Text , Select JSP , add the file extension you are trying to open in JSP editor